# problem with robot framework test in docker runner

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, appium, robotframework

I want to run my android tests with robot framework and appium on an android emulator with docker on a gitlab runner. after execution, i received these errors and job failed:

`$ docker run --network mobile_driver_test_automation_default --rm --mount "type=bind,src=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/robot/Reports,dst=/app/reports" qa/robot:latest python3 -m robot -d /app/reports /app/Tests/Login.robot`

> Init Page Assertion Design Chaneg Path                                [ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdd8c04ea00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /wd/hub/session
> [ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdd8c04ed60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /wd/hub/session
> [ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdd8c04eee0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /wd/hub/session
> [ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open
> | FAIL |
> MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='appium_server', port=4723): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdd8bff1880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

My docker-compose and gitlab.ci files are shown below:
docker-compose:

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  
  selenium_hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.14.0-curium
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

  appium_server:
    image: appium/appium:v1.22.3-p1
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
    network_mode: "service:selenium_hub"
    volumes:
      - ./robot/apk:/root/tmp/apk/
    environment:
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
      - RELAXED_SECURITY=true

  nexus_emulator:
    image: budtmo/docker-android-x86-10.0:v1.10-p7
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
      - appium_server
    volumes:
      - ./robot/apk:/root/tmp/apk/
    
    ports:
      - 6080:6080
      - 4723:4723
      - 5554:5554
      - 5555:5555

    environment:
      - DEVICE=Nexus 5
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - APPIUM=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
      - AUTO_RECORD=true
```

```
stages:
  - docker-login
  - build-robot
  - setup-test
  - run-test
  - docker-down

docker-login:
  stage: docker-login
  tags:
    - docker
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ "main"
  script:
    - docker login -u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD $ARTIFACTORY_REGISTRY

build-robot:
  stage: build-robot
  tags:
    - docker
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ "main"
  script:
    - docker build -t qa/robot:latest -f robot/Dockerfile robot

setup-test:
  stage: setup-test
  tags:
    - docker
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ "main"
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
    - docker ps

run-login-test:
  stage: run-test
  tags:
    - docker
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ "main"
  script:
    - docker ps
    - docker run --network mobile_driver_test_automation_default --rm --mount "type=bind,src=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/robot/Reports,dst=/app/reports"qa/robot:latest python3 -m robot -d /app/reports /app/Tests/Login.robot
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - robot/Reports/report.html
    expire_in: 3 day
  
docker-down:
  stage: docker-down
  tags:
    - docker
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ "main"
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml down
```

robot framework script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  AppiumLibrary
Library  Process

*** Test Cases ***

Init Page Assertion Design Chaneg Path
    Open Application   http://appium_server:4723/wd/hub    app=/app/robot/Tests/apk/driver.apk   autoGrantPermissions=true     platformName=Android  deviceName=Nexus 5  appPackage=packageName   appActivity=ActivityName  
    Log    "app opened succesfully"
```

and also my Dockerfile and project path picture:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to configure your tests to talk to `http://appium_server:4723/wd/hub`.  In the Compose configuration, though, you specify

```yaml
services:
  appium_server:
    network_mode: "service:selenium_hub"
```

This `network_mode:` setting is a very unusual setting that causes the `appium_server` container to not have its own network identity, but instead run inside the `selenium_hub` container's network namespace.  I'm not clear when you'd need this setting, beyond programs that have incorrectly hard-coded `localhost` as the location of some other service; making the service location configurable through an environment variable would be a better solution.

I think either of two things would work:

1. Delete the `network_mode:` line.  It's a strange configuration and hopefully unnecessary.
2. Configure your tests to use `selenium_hub` as the destination host name, because that's where this container actually is on the Docker internal network.